# Is my laptop temperature normal?

Tags: laptop, cpu, cooling, temperature

Here is my laptop temperature got from [Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php).

[image: Temperature]

The specification of my laptop:

- Processor: Intel Core i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz
- OS: Windows 10 RAM: 6GB
- Display drivers: AMD Radeon 6600M and 6700M Series, Intel HD Graphics
  3000

At the time I capture this, I only use 5 Chrome tabs.

Is this temperature normal? If it's too hot, what should I do? Thanks for your help!

Comment: its normal for a laptop under a bit of a load, yes.

Comment: normal if full of dust or slugware running in the background. Taking this screenshot implies you weren't playing a 3D game at the same time.

Comment: Yes, I didn't play game at the time I took this screenshot. Meanwhile, 51% of the memory were occupied. I don't see any suspicious process, the most usage belongs to something like `System`, `Google Chrome`, `Service Host`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty normal to me. At idle it might be a little on the warm side but nothing extraordinary. If you are worried about it and depending on your skill set; you could turn off the computer and pull out the battery and use pressurized air to clear the heatsink. Do the same thing but disconnect the fan plug to prevent the possibility of the controller burning out. Remove the heat sink and reapply thermal paste to it.

51% is also standard for 6gb, Google chrome and windows 10. For some reason it is quite the memory hog.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm just worried because the Speedfan said that my laptop was hot.

Comment: @AnhTriet, those are higher temps than anyone would like to see, but laptop cooling is generally hands-off (unconfigurable) and were built for people that think there is somthing wrong with their laptop because it is loud (from fans running) not because it is hot when they lounge with it on their bed with their covers blocking all the air vents.... For a desktop I'd say clean your fans and make sure they are all working. for a laptop, not really much you can do. usually they won't really spin up the fan until they breach 70C.